# Plain <select> element vs Bootstrap's dropdown element rendered on mobile device

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, google-chrome-devtools, mobile-website

Today I've learnt something new, that `<select>` element rendered completely different on a desktop and mobile browser. The problem that I haven't use it before and almost all stuff I've done,  is by using Bootstrap's elements. 
So my question is actually 2 questions are following:

1. Why `<select>` tag rendered differently on mobile chrome and desktop chrome when I debugging in mobile mode? Is it intended behaviour or I can consider it as bug? For example open following page http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp from desktop browser in dev mobile mode and on a hardware device, you will see the difference.
2. What is the best approach to achieve consistency across various devices? Can I be sure that in all new mobile devices `<select>` will be rendered "in a mobile way", or just implement my own select element based on [Bootstrap modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) combined with [List group](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#list-group) as I've done here: http://codepen.io/anatoly314/pen/EPBmrM?editors=1010 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DevTools Device Mode does not emulate mobile-specific UA handling of form elements. This is actually very tricky to do since those things are compiled for that platform build.

The best thing to do is know there will be a difference. In the case of select elements it really doesn't matter much. Since the mobile UX is a full screen scroll selector of the choices.

The absolute best thing, as always, is use Device Mode as a guideline. It is not absolute nor can it be. You will always need to do on-device testing to verify everything works as expected. DM simply gets you 85-90% of the way there without issue.